# Archiving to a different file to avoid heavy size (Emacs)

Tags: emacs, archiving

My archive file has a datetree format and over 30K lines. It is very very slow.

Is there a way to archive new entries from i.e., February 2021 onwards, to a new different archive, but when turning on the "show archive headings" in the agenda, show the ones in both archived files?

Thanks